# iOS: UITableViewCell - Cells interrupting/overlaying eachother

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, autolayout

I've build a UITableView with different costum cells. One is with a UIImageView and one without. But they are overlaying each other. I've set all constraints.

every cell owns its own section.

screens:
(image and text are samples.)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the actual cell height change?

If so, you need to make sure you're returning the correct height with:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return heightOfCell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might have the constraints wrong on the cell without the image as it is drawing beyond where the table thinks the height suggests it should end. Hence why it is drawing beyond where the second cell top starts.

Possible issues are:

0) You are returning a height from `heightForRowAtIndexPath` which is too small. Use auto layout for iOS8 or if suppoting iOS7, you will need to calculate the height.

1) Perhaps your constraints are wrong. Have you pinned the bottom text to the bottom of the cell contentView and the top of the date to the top of the contentView?

2) If using iOS8 auto layout, try adding `[self.tableView reloadData];` in viewWillAppear. Sometimes it needs an extra kick to get the layout right, especially if text needs resized. I have no explanation for this other than I had to do this and I've seen it mentioned a few times elsewhere.